# match the first character of WORD in elisp

Tags: elisp, regex-negation

I want to find an elisp regex that only finds the first character of a **word** (a set of non-whitespace characters).

This is what I have:

```
\\(^\\|\\(:?\[[:space:]\]\\)\\)\[^\n[:space:]\]
```

It's close but not exactly right.
It captures any non-whitespace character that has either whitespace or is at the beginning of the line. But it captures the whitespace and the beginning of line as well.

I'd I'm writing this for specific emacs method that takes in an elisp regex as a parameter, specifically avy--generic-jump.

This is what avy-generic-jump looks like:

```
'(avy--generic-jump REGEX WINDOW-FLIP STYLE &optional BEG END)'
```

And this is what I have now:

```
(avy--generic-jump "\\(?:^\\|\\(:?[[:space:]]\\)\\)[^\n[:space:]]" nil 'at))
```

Main Question: What can I do to match the first character of a **word** in elisp?

More general question: what's the proper way to deal with cases in elisp where you don't want to capture the whole match?

Comment: How are you using it specifically? If your pattern necessarily matches more text than you want, you would typically then extract the bits you *do* want from the match data.

Comment: I'll edit my question to add in the exact function I'm using it in

Comment: Also could you please elaborate on how to extract the bits you do want?

Comment: Generally using `match-string` or `match-data` after a regexp match, but it very much depends on what the code does. I don't know what `avy--generic-jump` is, or what its code looks like, so it's hard to say. If that's not your own function, and you need *it* to behave differently, then that's more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to create a new zero-width assertion in emacs is not possible. You basically need look-around support. You can try out this [patch](https://github.com/gamesun/emacs-regex-lookaround), or less instrusively, advising the avy--generic-jump function to adjusting the result position candidates off by one.

Here is an example to make avy jump off by one.

```
(defun avy--regex-candidates (regex &optional beg end pred group)
  "Return all elements that match REGEX.
Each element of the list is ((BEG . END) . WND)
When PRED is non-nil, it's a filter for matching point positions.
When GROUP is non-nil, (BEG . END) should delimit that regex group."
  (setq group (or group 0))
  (let ((case-fold-search (or avy-case-fold-search
                              (string= regex (downcase regex))))
        candidates)
    (avy-dowindows current-prefix-arg
      (dolist (pair (avy--find-visible-regions
                     (or beg (window-start))
                     (or end (window-end (selected-window) t))))
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (car pair))
          (while (re-search-forward regex (cdr pair) t)
            (unless (get-char-property (1- (point)) 'invisible)
              (when (or (null pred)
                        (funcall pred))
                (push (cons (cons (1+ (match-beginning group))
                                  (1+ (match-end group)))
                            wnd) candidates)))))))
    (nreverse candidates)))
```

Comment: How would you adjust the resulting position of a candidate by one?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest regex is something that matches a word boundary and then a word character:

```
"\\b\\w"
```

See what I mean by using `isearch-forward-regexp`

```
C-M-s \b\w
```

If you want to consider the boundary of a symbol, you can use:

```
"\\_<\\w"
```

Try it out with

```
C-M-s \_<\w
```

Like phils said, it depends on what the `avy--generic-jump` function does.  It looks like it just uses the Emacs Lisp function `re-search-forward`, so I think the above should work.

Note that you need to use double-slashes in Emacs regular expressions.  So your first attempt should have been:

```
(avy--generic-jump "\\(?:^\\|\\(:?[[:space:]]\\)\\)[^\n[:space:]]" nil 'at))
```

Comment: The problem with "\\b\\w" is that it matches too much. For example: ' define-key ' should capture only 'd'. but \\b\\w captures 'd' and 'k'.

Comment: And you're right I'm missing backslashes. I will amend that in my question.

Comment: Oh, ok, so maybe try `"\\_<\\w"`

Comment: The problem with this one is it misses symbols like '('. For example: '(hello world)' should capture '(' and 'w' but "\\_<\\w" would get "h" and "w".

Comment: Another close attempt I've made is: \\(^\\| \)\\[^\n\r\t\f ] but this still includes preceding spaces. I'm not sure if it's possible without lookbacks.

Comment: Ok, now that you better understand your requirements, or at least how to communicate them, want to start over and restate your question or leave  and start a new question?